# Jinja .css template logic

Tags: python, css, django, wagtail

I am wiring my framework to wagtail. It is a custom module css framework called reely.io that is made for Hubspot. It has jinja variables for breakpoints, colors, etc. one of the variables is a multiplier for padding and margin settings.

I have the css file set up and coming through to the template. the issue is with any logic in the css file:

```
{{ spacing_multiplier * 1 + 'px' }}
{{ break_sm + 30 + 'px' }}
```

Yes, this works in Hubspot's HubL, which I always considered a derivative of Jinja, but the syntax is a bit different. am I doing it wrong?

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class Themes(TemplateView):
    template_name = "css/reely.css"
    content_type = "text/css"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

        ''' Responsive Breaks '''
        context["break_xl"] = 1773
        context["break_lg"] = 1292
        context["break_md"] = 768
        context["break_sm"] = 576
        context["break_xs"] = 396

        ''' Spacing Multiplier '''
        context["spacing_multiplier"] = 10

        ''' Font '''
        context['google_font_link'] = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap"
        context['font_family_1'] = "'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;"

        ''' Color Set 1 '''
        context["primary_color"] = '#333333' '''rgb(51,51,51)'''
        context["secondary_color"] = '#555555' '''rgb(85,85,85)'''
        context["tertiary_color"] = '#FFFFFF' '''rgb(255,255,255)'''

        ''' Color Set 2 '''
        context["primary_font_color"] = '#333333' '''rgb(51,51,51)'''
        context["secondary_font_color"] = '#555555' '''rgb(85,85,85)'''
        context["tertiary_font_color"] = '#FFFFFF' '''rgb(255,255,255)'''

        ''' Color Set 3 '''
        context["accent_color_1"] = '#DD0000' '''rgb(221,0,0)'''
        context["accent_color_2"] = '#84C318' '''rgb(132,195,24)'''
        context["accent_color_3"] = '#F96900' '''rgb(249,105,0)'''
        context["success_color"] = '#28A745' '''rgb(40,167,69)'''
        context["info_color"] = '#17A2B8' '''rgb(23,162,184)'''
        context["warning_color"] = '#FFC107' '''rgb(255,193,7)'''
        context["danger_color"] = '#DC3545' '''rgb(255,193,7)'''

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("config/reely/css", views.Themes.as_view(),
         name="reelycss"),
]
```

expected output:

```
context["spacing_multiplier"] = 10
{{spacing multiplier * 30 +'px'}} = 10 * 3 = 30 + 'px' = '30px'
```

and I get that there are strings and ints here HubL doesn't have an issue with it. This doesn't work either.

```
context["spacing_multiplier"] = 10
{{spacing multiplier * 30 }} = 10 * 3 = 30 = 30
```

Comment: What's the expected and actual result you're getting from those expressions?

Comment: I added an expected output example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a custom template filter.

css:

```
{% load reely_tags %}

.ry [class*="pr3" i] {
  padding-right: {{spacing_multiplier|space:3}};
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

app/templatetags/reely_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name="space")
def space(value, size):
    output = str(value * size)
    return f"{output}px"
```

output css:

```
.ry [class*="pr3" i] {
  padding-right: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I'd be interested to know how Hubspot made HubL compared to Jinja2 now, or even what makes the difference in this type of functionality, but custom template tags are a good solution for this. I'm now able to wire the context variables for the css into my wagtail admin, which was the goal.